# Define multiple whisper directories in webapp configuration

Tags: graphite

i am running 4 carbon cache process behind carbon-relay on same machine with different LOCAL_DATA_DIR for each cache process.

i want to render whole aggregated metrics on webapp dashboard for which i am using below configuration in my local_settings.py.

```
STANDARD_DIRS = ['/graphite_data/01',
                 '/graphite_data/02',
                 '/graphite_data/03',
                 '/graphite_data/04']


CARBONLINK_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1:7102:1', '127.0.0.1:7202:2', '127.0.0.1:7302:3','127.0.0.1:7402:4']
```

but I am not getting any metrics on my dashboard. is there something wrong with configuration?